# Swift segue by identifer causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a navigation controller as the initial view. It goes to VC1 which has 3 buttons, and each button is tied to an action that sets a parameter in VC2 before invoking `performSegueWithIdentifier("goNow", sender: nil)`. I have this in my VC1 too.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goNow") {
        if let sView: SViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SViewController {
            sView.action = self.action
        }
    }
}
```

When invoked, VC2 appears for a few seconds and it terminates with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Well where's the crash happening? What's VC2 doing with the "action"?

Comment: the action is just some variable for me to show/hide labels in VC2. The crash just happen after the viewDidLoad() method. I have run breakpoints within the viewDidLoad() method, doesn't seem to be anything within it. I have tried debugging by setting VC2 as the initial VC and all the workflow behind it runs fine. Something is terribly wrong the VC1 passing on to VC2

Answer (score 0):

I am not extremely familiar with Swift, but I know that there are some questions when attempting to compare strings. Instead of using:`if (segue.identifier == "goNow")`

***~ edit ~***
Setting the class in Interface Builder (storyboard) for the destination view controller.

[image]

Create a String Variable using the `segue.identifier` value and compare the two like this:

```
let segueID = String(segue.identifier)
let segueToOpen = "goNow"
let isEqual = (segueID == segueToOpen)

// Now your if statement
if isEqual {
    // ...
}
```

Also, you might want to consider separating the logic in the next if statement to read something like:

```
let sView: SViewController = segue.destinationViewController
```

Here is an excerpt from RayWenderlick's site and using the `as` operator:

[image]

Comment: I did all the changes but still not helping.
Is this useful?

    0x1011b5808 <+1098>: movq   %r13, (%rsp)
    0x1011b580c <+1102>: leaq   0xb85efd(%rip), %r9       ; @"Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named %@ is loaded."
    0x1011b5813 <+1109>: movl   $0xbd3, %r8d
    0x1011b5819 <+1115>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x1011b581b <+1117>: movq   %rbx, %rdx

Comment: @RayWong have you made sure to set the correct class for the Destination VC in your storyboard? In the Utilities Inspector choose **identity inspector** and set the class to SViewController. See my edit

Comment: It seems that there is a issue with invoking segue programatically. I removed all the codes and create segue using the UI drag and drop and call the segue name and it works fine